# STHTTPRequest "& char" how i can send this char to a php page?

Tags: php, ios, character-encoding, sthttprequest

My ios app have to send/retrive some date throught some php pages. This is an example call usingi STHTTPRequest :

```
 __block STHTTPRequest *up = [STHTTPRequest requestWithURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",PATHSERVER,@"retrivedata.php"]];

up.encodePOSTDictionary=NO;
up.postDataEncoding=NSUTF8StringEncoding;

up.POSTDictionary = @{@"name":@"Name", @"surname":@"Surname"};
```

It's all ok until i decide to insert something lik :

```
up.POSTDictionary = @{@"name":@"Na&me", @"surname":@"Surname"};
```

In this way a

```
 print_r($_POST);
```

in retrivedata.php results in:

```
Array
(
 [name] => Na
 [surname] => Surname

)
```

The name is cutted at the "&" char index. I have tried with no success something like:

```
utf8_encode/utf8_decode($name)
```

It seems that name arrives to retrivedata.php already cutted, so i can't use any chars conversion/encoding... In my STHTTPRequest i have already tried to set:

```
up.encodePOSTDictionary=YES;
```

With this setting i can send "&" as $amp; but if i do a SELECT to retrive the value i can't convert it to the normal string by

```
 html_entity_decode();
```

it still remain

```
&amp;
```

How i can do? My STHTTPRequest send 'Na&me' but it comes blank to $_POST[] in retrivepage.php

Answer (score 1):

I am not really familiar with the shttprequest, but you should url encode it. It will look like **"Na%26me"** when URL encoded. Later in the post you will have **"Na&me"**

Hope it helps :)